# How to force execution of overriden method of a mocked autowired field in JUnit tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I have a CacheInterceptor class that extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter. This class has an autowired Cache:

```
// CacheInterceptor.java
public class CacheInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Cache<String, String> myCache;

    ...
}
```

This bean definition happens in CachingConfiguration class. Inside this class, I'm overriding Cache write method due to additional behavior that is needed by the project.

```
// CachingConfiguration.java
public class CachingConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "myCache")
    public Cache<String, String> getMyCache() {
        ...

        CacheWriter<String, String> writer = new CacheWriter<String, String>() {

            @Override
            public void write(String key, String value) throws Exception {
                object.persist();
                ...
            }
    }
}
```

Then I have a CacheInterceptorTest class, in which I'm mocking myCache because there are some situations that I need to force the value to be returned.

```
// CacheInterceptorTest.java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        CachingConfiguration.class
})

public class CacheInterceptorTest {

    @MockBean
    private Cache<String, String> myCache;
}
```

This works for most of my tests. However, there is one specific test that needs that the `write()` method inside getMyCache gets called when putting a value in Cache. But because I'm mocking it, it is using the original implementation of Cache.write().

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you want to describe what test requires that behavior and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mock is an independent implementation, it does not have the overwritten method, so there is no way to "force" anything.

Depending on what you want to achieve in your tests, different solutions are possible.

Easy solutions can be to use a real Cache in your junit test, or a dummy (not mock) Cache that always reads-writes to the real storage.